# Pass parameter to Ressource's method callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, crud, angular-resource

I'm trying to change some model data if I sucessfully update something in my API :

```
this.saveProject = function(project) {
  var editedProjectSupport = {
        /* some data */
  };
  SupportTimeTracks.update({id: project.backendId}, editedProjectSupport,
    function() {
      // There :
      project.department = controllerScope.edit.project.department;
      project.timetrack = controllerScope.edit.project.timetrack;
      growl.success('Project support successfully edited');
    },
    function(result) {
      growl.error('Project support couldn\'t be edited.');
      console.log(result);
    });
  this.edit.project = {};
  $scope.$broadcast('edit.project');
};
```

But I can't access `project` in my success callback `function()`. Is there anyway to pass it in parameter or something else.

How can I update my `project.department` & `project.timetrack` ?

The function is called from the view, `project` is local in the function (although it references to an element present in the scope)

Comment: I think `$resource` returns a special promise object; try `return SupportTimeTracks.update().$promise.then(function(result))`

Comment: This will allow me to access to the inserted data, but not to my `project` variable which is present only in front-end

Comment: Wouldn't you do precisely that in the `then` function?

Comment: Afaik, the context is different in promise/then, which mean we can't access to external data. That's also why I have a global `controllerScope` referenced to `this`. And the same goes for resource method (save, remove, update...)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.saveProject = function(project) {

  SupportTimeTracks.update({id: project.backendId}, editedProjectSupport,
    function() {
      // There : if you are not *shadowing* project variable, you MUST have access to project variable.
    }
  );
};
```

Your function is a closure, `project` is a variable defined in `this.saveProject`, so if you are not having another variable defined inside with the same name (**shadowing** your first variable) `project` have to be defined and with the value you have passed to `this.saveProject` and you **have** to have access to it.

### Code example:

```js
var closure = function(project){
  // I grab project var here
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert('there is no project shadowing: '+ project);
  }, 100);
};

closure('my project var');

var closureWithShadowing = function(project){
  // I grab project var here ... but
  setTimeout(function(){
    var project = 'I eat project variables'; // I have created a new var with the same name
             // so, I'm shadowing the original one.
    alert('project shadowing: '+ project);
  }, 500);
};

closureWithShadowing('my project var');
```

Comment: What do you mean by project should be *this* ?
The function is called from the view and project is a binded model : `<a class="clickable btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-click="t.saveProject(project)">`. So project is actually local to the function

Comment: I mean if *this* of *this.saveProject* reference to project.

Comment: I already have my example working... sorry for make so many changes